# Kids' novel with literal-minded robot son going to high school

Tags: story-identification

I read this shortish young adult/kids book probably in the early 2000s, but I believe it was probably a couple of decades older. The cover was /very/ 80s, I recall, with realistic (but drawn, not photographed) people doing some sort of action-ish scene. I think the surrounding space was navy blue.

The plot concerned a man who created a young teenage robot son and sent him to school (probably early high school?). No one there knew he was a robot. The son looked human, but was very bad at interacting with his classmates because he didn't understand social cues at all. He always spoke and interpreted others extremely literally.

A couple of details I remember:

1) The boy had to charge himself through ports that were hidden under his skin. He was also extremely strong and fast.

2) There was a scene where he got in trouble with a teacher and was trying to recount an incident, but accidently recounted it while perfectly mimicing the voices of the people he'd been with, so it made the teacher angry.

3) I'm pretty sure at least one girl had a crush on him, and he was very confused about that. She used some euphemisms that went over his head.

4) His robot body was fallible--I don't remember specifics, but I think it might be that he was vulnerable to water or electrical surges or things of that nature.

This book may have been the first of a series, but if it was I never read the others. I think the title was like 'Main Title: Subtitle.'

Comment: Totally OT, but this sorts of remind me a bit of the movie "D.A.R.Y.L." (1985) with Barret Olivier...  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088979/

Comment: The poster is drawn.  The movie got a sub-title: "D.A.R.Y.L. - He can't be kept secret any longer".  A girl in his class winks at him.  He corrects a paper and comments about an error "in the fifth decimal place" (or something".  When confronted by his teacher, he mimics the teacher's tick.  He records everything and it can be played back (could be confused with mimicking voices).  He's part of a research project for the army, but an older man is his "father".  He SPOILER *pretends* do "die" from drowning.  He actually got a human body, but with a computer brain.  http://youtu.be/3upS3idcSpE

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*[Not Quite Human #1: Batteries Not Included](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/653714.Batteries_Not_Included)* by Seth McEvoy

> Professor Carson has created the most fantastic of his works: an
>   android with the appearance of a boy of thirteen. Connected to
>   batteries, walking, talking, thinking – his metal body is covered with
>   a skin of plastic and you would never imagine that his blonde hair is
>   nylon... The professor calls him Chip.
>
> To complete the experiment, Dr. Carson has enrolled Chip in Harbor
>   College where he himself teaches science. But can Chip keep his
>   secret?

In chapter 2 he is taken to the school psychologist and replays his earlier conversation with Coach Duckworth switching voices.

From chapter 6:

> ...Erin walked up behind him. "Hi, Chip! I've been meaning to tell you - that's a nice sweater you're wearing. It matches the color of your eyes."
>
> "Thank you," he replied, closing the locker door.
>
> "You know, Chip, I sure am glad you moved here."
>
> "Why?" he asked.
>
> "Because you're so much fun to be around. I'd like to see more of you."
>   "Which parts?" asked Chip, examining his body.
>
> Erin turned red with embarrassment. "All of you," she said.
>
> "I'll have to ask my dad if you want to see all of me."

Comment: Oh no, imagine being this poor girl! *cringe*

Comment: This is it! I'd recognized that ridiculously 80s cover anywhere. :D Thank you much.

Comment: The tv show / films were the answer to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/165495/need-help-finding-an-old-tv-show-80s-90s/165772#165772 with the book and tv series suggested [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/220068/series-between-1980-2000-about-humanoid-boy-trying-to-live-like-a-human/220073#220073).