# Series between 1980 - 2000 about humanoid boy trying to live like a human

Tags: story-identification, androids

Trying to look for a series between 1980 - 2000, where the son was an android trying live a human life.

I can remember everyday he had to pull the cable out of his stomach to charge himself.

Comment: Was this a TV series or a series of books?

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing whether you meant a book series or TV series, I was going to suggest the [*Not Quite Human*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_Quite_Human) series of books by Seth McEvoy, started in 1985. In the meantime, I discovered that it had also been made into TV movies (the first one is from 1987), so that will do for both!

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093649/):

> Dr. Jonas Carson, a scientist, invents Chip, an android teenager. Dr. Carson sends Chip to school with his daughter Becky to see whether an android could interact with others. But his former employer decides to try and make a profit by stealing the mechanical boy.

Chip frequently has to recharge through a plug in his ankle (not his belly).

[image: French book cover, android boy plugging himself to the wall]